# Simulators Keep Timing Out Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

Ever since I've downloaded Xcode 8 beta (first installed 3 updates ago) I cannot get anything to run in the simulator. Everytime I try to run a program (even just an empty one) it takes forever to even boot up the Apple load bar in the simulator, it eventually just times out.

I keep on having to revert to Xcode 7 to do my work which is frustrating. Xcode 7 works fine. Xcode 8 is impossible to do anything on.

I've just installed the Xcode 8 GM release and thought this would solve the issue but again everything is the same. No luck.

I'm not sure if its my hardware spec that can't handle it. I've got a 2013 Macbook Air with 4GB RAM. Has anyone else been able to use Xcode 8 with 4GB RAM? The fans kick in when I run the simulator which suggests so... No fans in Xcode 7 though.

Another thing is that I've ended up with a ton of duplicate simulators. I have like six iPhone 6 SE simulators.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You should post the duplicate simulators as a separate question. Personally, I'd love to see an answer for that. I've had to delete them manually, one at a time in the devices window. Yes, hundreds of them.

Comment: I've had this issue as well, uninstalling Xcode 8 GM, restarting the machine and then reinstalling fixed it for me.